# name for a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

is there a way to refer to a pivot table using a range name?  I want to have another table with calculations based on what's in the pivot table, but I want to use range names to make sure my calculations are still correct if the size of the pivot table changes.

Answer (score 1):

The code at this blogpost of mine will probably get you half the way there: http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/10/18/introducing-structured-references-for-pivottables/

It generates automatic named ranges to reference parts of PivotTables, in a similar manner as what happens natively for Tables.

And this post from Jon Peltier will probably get you the rest of the way: http://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/